# Tracking runtime in seconds

Tags: r, time, runtime

I'm creating machine learning models and in order to score the performance of my models, one aspect that I am looking at is the time that it takes for the model to run.

I have the following code:

```
  start_time <- Sys.time()
  predictions <- class.tree.predictions(traindata, testdata)
  end_time <- Sys.time()
  run_time <- end_time - start_time
```

When there is a time difference of seconds the output is "Time difference of 0.23204 sec" but when the time difference is in minutes the output is "Time difference of 1.05204 mins".

I need the output to only be in seconds, or I need an if statement for when the time difference is in minutes, so it can get multiplied by 60, but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Comment: I can recommend the [tictoc package](https://collectivemedia.github.io/tictoc/) for this problem; using purpose-built functions can often result in fewer issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`difftime` has an option for `units`:

```
difftime(end_time, start_time, units="secs")
```